# How to find the IP of a server address using cmd

Tags: windows, networking, ip

How do we find the IP of a server address (like `http://google.com` is `209.85.148.103`) using the Windows CMD?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
ping google.com
```

or

```
nslookup google.com
```

Comment: worked for me..

Answer (score 6):

You can also use:

> `tracert google.com`

Answer (score 2):

Ping google.com. More correctly, use NSlookup google.com

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following in your command-line prompt:

```
pathping google.com
```

Comment: Good idea =)  ​​​​​