# How to get the ip address of a computer from its hostname?

Tags: networking, batch, ip, lan, hostname

I have the name of a computer on the network, and I need to know how to get the ip address of said computer from a batch file? Thanks.

Comment: You could `ping <hostname>` to get the IP.

Comment: That gives the MAC address

Comment: Mark - I'd like to see the `ping <hostname>` with a batch script return the MAC address—that doesn't sound right to me. For example from command line you can run `for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %a in ('ping <hostname> -n 1') do echo %a` to get an IP address from Windows 10 for example. What type of special configuration are you working with or help clarify on that statement a bit otherwise about getting the MAC address.

Comment: another duplicate: [How to find the IP of a server address using cmd](https://superuser.com/q/303550/241386)

Comment: Indeed a dupe, missed those sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem can be solved via command. Like the picture I posted below. You may have mistakenly marked the yellow mark as a MAC address, but they are actually IPv6 addresses. When you use the ping command, you can add "-4" behind the host name to display the IPv4 address.

```
ping hostname -4
```

[image]

I also have a batch file that returns the hostname and IP address of the computer at the same time. You can write the following code to a txt file and change the extension to `.bat`. Then double-click the file to get the computer name and ip address. I hope this will help you.

Code:

```
@echo off

 title Display your IP and hostname

 color F9

 @echo -

 for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('ipconfig^|findstr "Address"') do set ip=%%i

 @echo Your ip address is :%ip%

 @echo Your computer name is :%COMPUTERNAME%

Echo press any key to exit...

pause>NUL
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this web page ([1](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/find-hostname-from-ip-address-to.html)), you can use the `nslookup` ([2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490950(v%3dtechnet.10))) command to print out some information about a computer including its IP based on its hostname address. You could then filter out only the IP using `findstr` ([3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490907(v=technet.10))).