# Recover the IP address of a remote machine knowing its hostname + ip address of the network + sshkey registered

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-desktop, ip, ssh-keys

I want to remotely ssh a computed administered by only me. The machine is always on a fixed IP (`network`; I do not know the technical name for that). To ssh I use `ssh [machine_name]@[machine_addr]` (again, I do not know the technical name for that). But somehow, after restarting the remote machine, the `machine_addr` change sometimes (why? how to stop that?) and forces me to physically visit the site to recover it using `ifconfig`. Is there a way to recover using the `machine_name` in this case. I tried [How to get the ip address of a computer from its hostname?](https://superuser.com/questions/1349780/how-to-get-the-ip-address-of-a-computer-from-its-hostname) Interestingly, the local machine from where I am trying has the same `machine_name`, is also on the `network`, (so doing `ping machine_name -4` returns `machine_addr` of my local machine). I have `ssh-key` registered meaning I could login passwordlessly if know `machine_addr`. Thanks.

Comment: See if your DHCP-server has the capability to "reserve" (lock) an IP for the machine.

Comment: Is it really machine_name or does it just happen to be similar? Normally the syntax of an ssh address is `[User_name]@[machine_address]`.

Comment: Another configuration possible for the DHCP server is to set it use a sub-segment of its IP range, thus liberating a few IP addresses. You may use these IP addresses as static IP, setting the IP in the network adapter properties of the target computer.

Comment: (1) "_The machine is always on a fixed IP_" and (2) "_after restarting the remote machine, the machine_addr change sometimes_". One of those statements cannot be true. Do you perhaps _want_ the machine to be on a fixed IP address?

Comment: "_the local machine from where I am trying has the same machine_name_" - that will lead to needless complexity. Can you rename one of the machines?

Comment: @roaima yes, the network IP is already fixed, but the device IP is not, it changes upon few restarts. Now, as I mentioned, I do not specifically know how to tell this properly.

Comment: @harrymc do you want to give an answer, even a partial one

Answer (score 0):

You explained in [a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1811097/recover-the-ip-address-of-a-remote-machine-knowing-its-hostname-ip-address-of?noredirect=1#comment2844174_1811097) that, "*the network IP is already fixed, but the device IP is not*".

There are two possibilities here,

1. You have not set a Static IP address on the device but are relying on the DHCP server to give you the correct address each time, but it does not.

   This is the easiest way to solve the problem: you ask your infrastructure people to assign the appropriate IP address in the DHCP server. You will need to provide them with the MAC address of the interface and they should be able to associate that with your reserved IP address so that the DHCP server always gives you the correct and expected address.
2. You have not set a Static IP address on the device but you cannot rely on the DHCP server to give you the correct address each time.

   In this instance you need to configure your device to use a Static (fixed) IP address instead of asking for an address from the DHCP server. Because you haven't specified the type of device (UNIX? Linux? If Linux which distribution?) it's not possible to provide specific instructions, only general advice

Answer (score 0):

The fact that IP address of the computer changes means that its IP address
allocation is dynamic and is not really fixed.
If you want the IP address to never change, it needs to be a
[static IP address](https://nordvpn.com/blog/what-is-static-ip/).

To create a static IP address, you need to avoid it conflicting
with the addresses given by the DHCP server.

If you can have configuration changes effected on the DHCP server,
the simplest method is to restrict its range of IP addresses
to exclude some addresses from being allocated.

Setting the DHCP server to use a (large) sub-segment of its IP range
will liberate a few IP addresses to be used as static IP.
You may set this IP on the target computer in the network adapter
properties.

This IP address will then be static and never change.